# Problem in binding input type radio in MVC VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm facing issue in binding input type radio button in mvc vb.net. I'm passing the value in model property but unable to bind the radio button based on values. Below is the html of radio button:

```
Checking:<input type="radio" id="rdChecking" name="C" value="Checking"/>
        Savings:<input type="radio" id="rdSavings" name="S" value="Savings" />
```

Here I've defined model:

```
Public Class AgencySweepSettingsModel
    ....
    ....
    Public Property AccountTypeChecking As String
    Public Property AccountTypeSaving As String
End Class
```

Here I'm passing values in model property:

```
If dsAgencySweepInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(5) = "C" Then
                            .AccountTypeChecking = "C"
                        Else
                            .AccountTypeSaving = "S"
                        End If
```

Please tell me how to bind this radio button.

Comment: The `name` attributes of you radio buttons need to match the name of the property. It not clear what you are wanting to do, but bset guess is you want one property (say `AccountType`) and then the radio buttons will be `<input type="radio" name="AccountType" value="Saving" />` and `<input type="radio" name="AccountType" value="Checking" />`. But you should never be generating the inputs manually - use the strong typed `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use strongly-typed [`@Html.RadioButtonFor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) helper to resolve radio button binding issue as in example below:

**Model**

```
Public Class AgencySweepSettingsModel
    ' other properties

    Public Property AccountType As String
End Class
```

**View**

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function (model) model.AccountType, "Checking", New With { Key .id = "rdChecking" })<label for="rdChecking">Checking</label>

@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function (model) model.AccountType, "Savings", New With { Key .id = "rdSavings" })<label for="rdSavings">Savings</label>
```

**Controller Action**

```
Public Function ActionName() As ActionResult
    Dim model As AgencySweepSettingsModel = New AgencySweepSettingsModel()

    ' other stuff

    ' assume dsAgencySweepInfo is a DataSet

    If dsAgencySweepInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(5) = "C" Then
        model.AccountType = "Checking"
    Else
        model.AccountType = "Savings"
    End If

    ' other stuff

    Return View(model)    
End Function

<HttpPost()>
Public Function ActionName(ByVal model As AgencySweepSettingsModel) As ActionResult
    ' do something
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

If you still want to use standard `BindAttribute` instead of strongly-typed viewmodel, then the `name` attribute for `<input>` elements must match with `Include` part that contains property name for both radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="rdChecking" name="AccountType" value="Checking"/><label for="rdChecking">Checking</label>
<input type="radio" id="rdSavings" name="AccountType" value="Savings" /><label for="rdSavings">Savings</label>
```

Note that since radio button always have only one selected value in the same group, you should use single property which bound to multiple `<input type="radio" />` elements.